# Bitcoin Transaction Stuck, Attempt to double spend with higher fees

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend

I made a BTC transaction a few days ago, where I set the fee amount way too low. It seemed that the transaction was lost in limbo.

I did some research, and apparently you are able to double spend your btc, if the transaction hasn't been confirmed yet.

So I imported my wallet into Bitcoin Core, where the unconfirmed transaction wasn't shown, and I was able to initiate another transaction with higher fees.

Now it seems that Blockchain.info doesn't show my transaction, and pushing it manually results in a mempool conflict. The same happened with this service: https://coinb.in/#broadcast.

But I was able to push the transaction through https://localbitcoinschain.com/. Now the transaction ID is unconfirmed on localbitcoinschain, but can't be found anywhere else (Blockchain.info, coinb.in).

Can this second transaction be approved, or is it impossible, if its only recognized by localbitcoinschain.com?
How should I proceed? At this rate, my transaction seems to be lost for a long time.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi @drGesus You provide valuable information, however, this Question and Answer are very unstructured. Please rephrase your question and answer. Otherwise this question may get closed.

Comment: As @nulldev suggests, the content from this question might be very useful to other users, I'd suggest posting the steps as an answer to this question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

My second transaction, although only listed on LocalBitcoinschain and nowhere else has been approved.